# Replacing text in log file if criteria match

Tags: powershell

I have logfile1 that I am pulling the variables `$a`, `$up`, `$left`.  I have logfile2 that I am pulling the variables `$b`, `$down`, `$right`.  My goal is to replace any line in logfile1 with the data from logfile2 where `$a` = `$b`, `$up` = `$down`, and `$left` = `$right`, as long as all 3 match.  If any of the variables do not match, I would like to create a new line in logfile1 with the values of `$b`, `$down`, and `$right`.  Right now I have these logfiles in .log formats, but I could change them to CSV or any other file type if that would be easier.

--Begin Edit

Each variable is pulled from its respective log file using this basic format:

```
$logfilea = '\b\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}'
select-string -Path $logfileone -Pattern $logfilea -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value} | Set-Variable -Name a
 $logfileup = '([a-zA-Z] [a-zA_Z] ([a-zA_Z]))'
select-string -Path $logfileone -Pattern $logfileup -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value} | Set-Variable -Name up
 $logfileright = '([a-zA-Z] [a-zA_Z] ([a-zA_Z]))'
select-string -Path $logfileone -Pattern $logfileright -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value} | Set-Variable -Name up

$logfileb = '\b\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}'
select-string -Path $logfiletwo -Pattern $logfileb -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value} | Set-Variable -Name b
 $logfiledown = '([a-zA-Z] [a-zA_Z] ([a-zA_Z]))'
select-string -Path $logfiletwo -Pattern $logfiledown -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value} | Set-Variable -Name down
 $logfileleft = '([a-zA-Z] [a-zA_Z] ([a-zA_Z]))'
select-string -Path $logfiletwo -Pattern $logfileleft -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value} | Set-Variable -Name left
```

Variables `$a` & `$b` are Time Values.  `$up` and `$down` are two text objects with a 3rd object in parenthesis.  `$right` and `$left` are text objects within parenthesis.  All data matches in their patterns.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of how those variables are set and the format of each of the log files? Typically, the helpers do not write code from scratch with no provided starter code. Otherwise, there is a chance this question gets voted for closure due to being too broad.

Comment: I edited my original post since I'm not very familiar with this forum and how its replys work.